# SQL Fetching sessions based on an interval of 30 minutes

Tags: sql, dql, gaps-and-islands

The title probably leaves some questions so I'll explain into detail.

I have a (MySQL) table containing chat messages, These messages all havea datetime column of the date when they're added.

Now that I want to achieve is that I fetch the amount of sessions that were had.

Now, what is a session? A new session starts when there is a duration of 30 minutes or more since the previous message.

So for example with the data:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:01
2014-01-01 00:20:01
2014-01-01 00:40:01
2014-01-01 00:60:01
```

Would be one session

```
2014-01-01 00:00:01 <--
2014-01-01 00:32:01 <--
2014-01-01 00:35:01
2014-01-01 01:00:01
2014-01-01 02:00:01 <--
2014-01-01 02:20:01
```

Would be three sessions starting anew where I placed the arrow on the start.

I don't neccecarily need the DQL example MySQL would be fine, I hope someone can help me with this.

Edit: The answer given below seems to work in the fiddle but not on our MySQL servers running 5.5.4, Wondering if this is a certain setting or that sqlFiddle is just not working as intended.

Comment: 30 minutes from when?  The start of every hour?  Some random message?  What happens if you have messages every 5 minutes for 3 hours?  Are you counting forwards in time (how do you pick starting points), or backwards from current (which could change your sessions)?  This is some form of gap-analysis, which MySQL isn't terribly well suited for (most other RDBMSs have features that would give additional support for things like this).

Comment: I was hoping my example would make enough sense. So yes, it would start on a message, and end on the last message which falls within the range of 30 minutes of the last message.

Unfortunately I cannot move away from MySQL, I'm stuck to MySQL and PHP

Comment: And a message every 5 minutes for three hours would result in a 3 hour session.

Comment: Then you might want to edit your question to read something like "a session ends when there have been no new messages for 30 minutes".  Or "A new session starts when there is a duration of 30 minutes or more since the previous message".  Which is thankfully much easier than what I initially thought you wanted.  You're going to need to construct a `LAG()` function, essentially... give me a bit here.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL unfortunately doesn't have what are known as windowing functions (which most other major RDBMSs do), so we have to dummy up one of our own.  This isn't actually all that difficult here, but it'd be nice to have the support...

Anyways, I said we needed to dummy up a `LAG()` function, but it's really so we can compare to increment a grouping counter, so we can actually cut out a step, sorta:

```
SELECT sentAt,
       @Session := IF(sentAt < @SessionBoundary, @Session, @Session + 1) AS session,
       @SessionBoundary := ADDTIME(sentAt, '00:30:00') AS sessionBoundary
FROM Message
JOIN (SELECT @Session := 0) n
ORDER BY sentAt
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a7994/2)</kbd>

Critically, note that, as it's good practice to use an 'exclusive upper-bound' (`<`) for positive continuous-range types (like [date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)), it's the **30th** minute that actually starts your new session.  That is, an initial message at 13:00 means the next session starts at 13:30 (given no additional messages).  This has the nice property of making everything line up nicely, and that I don't have to worry about strange behavior with fractional seconds that I might not have specified.
In any case, this returns results like so:

```
sentAt               session  sessionBoundary
2014-01-01 00:00:01  1        2014-01-01 00:30:01 
2014-01-01 00:32:01  2        2014-01-01 01:02:01 
2014-01-01 00:35:01  2        2014-01-01 01:05:01 
2014-01-01 01:00:01  2        2014-01-01 01:30:01
2014-01-01 02:00:01  3        2014-01-01 02:30:01
2014-01-01 02:20:01  3        2014-01-01 02:50:01
```

Now, since all you wanted was a simple count of how many `session`s there were, you can wrap it as a subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(session)
FROM (SELECT sentAt,
             @Session := IF(sentAt < @SessionBoundary, @Session, @Session + 1) AS session,
             @SessionBoundary := ADDTIME(sentAt, '00:30:00') AS sessionBoundary
      FROM Message
      JOIN (SELECT @Session := 0) n
      ORDER BY sentAt) MessageSession
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a7994/6/0)</kbd>
(Note: for some reason I don't understand, using the initial work as a subquery is causing the fiddle to start at 0 instead of the 1 it was at before.  Please test this on your server, as you may need to initialize with `@Session = 1` instead of 0, or use something like `COUNT(DISTINCT session)`).

...And we're done.

---

Although you only listed wanting the count, once you have the session grouping you can have all sorts of fun with your data.  It's now trivial to get the `MAX(sentAt)`/`MIN(sentAt)` per-group, count of how many messages were in a group, or whatever.  For instance, you could say "find all long running sessions" via something like this:

```
SELECT session, 
       MIN(sentAt) AS firstMessageAt, MAX(sentAt) AS lastMessageAt, COUNT(*) AS messages
FROM (SELECT sentAt,
             @Session := IF(sentAt < @SessionBoundary, @Session, @Session + 1) AS session,
             @SessionBoundary := ADDTIME(sentAt, '00:30:00') AS sessionBoundary
      FROM Message
      JOIN (SELECT @Session := 0) n
      ORDER BY sentAt) MessageSession
GROUP BY session
HAVING ADDTIME(MIN(sentAt), '24:00:00') < MAX(sentAt)
```

(find all session that have been running for at least 24 hours)

Comment: I'll keep this one in my memory, trying to convert my query to DQL now, probably easier than using your sollution. Seems like a better one though.

Comment: Since my sollution seemed to be crap I'm looking at yours however for some reason it doesn't seem to do any grouping in your last example. I guess I'll find out why it surely is faster than my subquery madness.

Comment: Ah yes, can't seem to find out why yet, but the IF never goes false.

Comment: As I'm looking at this now, it seems that the SessionBoundry variable is always set when doing the IF statement, thus resulting in an always Higher than.

If you have time could you help me out with this one? I'll see if I can fix this though.

Comment: It's not, actually - in the examples I've given, the comparison against `@SessionBoundary` is happening for the _next_ row (by the given ordering).  My guess is you've moved the `@SessionBoundary := ADDTIME(sentAt, '00:30:00') AS sessionBoundary` to **before** the `IF ...`; [you can't do that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a7994/11/0), it has to come after it.  In these cases, order of instructions seems to be preserved.  Unless you've maybe got some funky server settings?  Otherwise, if you have a more specific example, maybe edit your question?

Comment: I didn't move it to before the If. But in the fidsle it is also not working. I tried lots of things but i started by just setting the correct column name :(.

Comment: @MathijsSegers - the fiddles in my answer are working properly for me (besides the 'starting at 0' thing).The fact that `@Session` changes **at all** is an indication that the `IF` evaluates to false on occasion.  The one in my previous comment is _meant_ to be 'failing'.  If you could provide an example of what's giving you trouble, I'd be better able to assist you.

Comment: I see the first fiddle works correctly, I'll play around and I'll let you know if I came further or not, thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm running MySQL 5.4, I tested the fiddle on 5.1 5.55 and 5.6 (if I'm correct) Which indeed works, but locally it just tells me no no, every single record is a session now.

Comment: It does however start with 1 locally... the session value.

Comment: The most probable explanation is that you've forgotten a character somewhere.  Like perhaps the `:` in `@Session := IF(...` - this would make the lone `=` act as a comparison, resulting in all 1's (evaluated as true), making it seem like everything is part of the same session.  [Something like this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a7994/14/0).

Comment: Well I assume it has todo with some settings in MySQL We have,

I basicly created a table, and copied and pasted the structure, afterwards the query, and every session was added to a new number.

So I couldn't have forgotten anything since it's a direct copy. I guess sqlFiddle works differently that real MySQL or I have some strange settings, but I cannot change these anyway since it has to work on production servers.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case I resolved it using a query like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    chat c
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    chat c2 
        WHERE   c2.date_add <= (c.date_add + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
        AND     c2.date_add > c.date_add
        )
```

The only issue here is that I cannot see when the session started, but this is enough functionality for my particular case. I'll gladly accept a better answer!

Comment: Your solution shows the LAST message from a session. My solution shows the FIRST message in a session, which I understand that you prefer. All I did was invert your time window.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is that SQL is a non procedural language when the problem is procedural.

Your proposal is a reasonable query that can be done in pure SQL. If you want to go further, I would advice you to use a procedural script, that can be written in many languages, Python, Perl, Ruby ...

In pseudo language, it could be :

```
long last=-1800  // time of previous line
long beg = -1    // begin time for current session
CREATE_QUERY_FOR : SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dat) FROM chat ORDER BY dat
LOOP_PER_LINE_FETCHED getting dat

if (dat - last > 30 * 60)
then 
    if last != -1 // we had a session
    then NOTE SESSION begin at beg and ending at last
    endif

    beg = dat   // start a new session
endif

last = dat

END_LOOP
```

IMHO it is the only way (or at least the simplest and most efficient) to get all sessions with begin and end - but I must admit it may not be what you are asking for ...

Comment: Yeah I don't really feel like fetching a few 10k's of records and start to iterate through them. Clockwork's fiddle works fine, but for some reason it's not working on my test environment.

Comment: @MathijsSegers : You do not have to fetch all records before processing. All the scripting languages cited allow to process records at the time they are fetched, or more precisely to fetch the records one at a time, or by batches of definite size.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  distinct *
FROM    chat c
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    chat c2 
        WHERE   c2.date_add > (c.date_add - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
        AND     c2.date_add < c.date_add
        )
```

Comment: No I need both, and besides this query is too slow, takes minutes in my test so it's a no-go.

Comment: If you want both then just union your query with mine.
And I don't see how the performance characteristics of this query could be substantially different from yours. They are the same but with the logic inverted.

Comment: As I said in some different comment, the query I made myself is also too slow. It takes minutes to fetch information I need on the fly.